# Why does Flowredirect with client polling after application server restart throw exceptions?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, spring-webflow

I have a simple polling mechanism that gets loaded in every page :

```
<h:form id="keepAliveForm">
   <p:poll interval="300" global="false"/>
</h:form>
```

In my main flow an end-state to redirect to a certain page:

```
<end-state id="redirect" view="flowRedirect:home" />
```

A button on another page and a transition in the view-state to the redirect flow:

```
<p:commandButton value="Test" action="theTest"/>

<transition on="theTest" to="redirect" />
```

Now everything is working, except when the application server (tomcat 7) gets restarted and there is still a client on a page that was redirected with the polling in.

Then every time when the polling fires I keep getting following exception :

```
 9-okt-2013 11:01:12 com.sun.faces.util.Util checkIdUniqueness
 SEVERE: JSF1007: Duplicate component ID j_idt65 found in view.
 9-okt-2013 11:01:12 com.sun.faces.util.Util checkIdUniqueness
```

and also :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
```

Why are these exceptions being thrown? And is there a way to stop them, because they do not really break the application, but fill the logs with unnecessary clutter.

Comment: Can you tell the scope of your bean?

Comment: @miroslav_mijajlovic At the moment there isn't a bean attached to the view that gets redirected too. Just a page with an inputtext pointing to no where, and a commandbutton that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Do you have your tomcat configured to persist sessions to disk in the event of a server shutdown/recycle?

Comment: @kolossus No, just a normal configured tomcat.

Comment: @kolossus Apparently starting from a certain version of Tomcat, the persist session is auto configured to be on. So apparently yes, sorry for the mix up.

Comment: @Lyrion - turn the session saving off. Tomcat persists view states,Viewscoped beans along with the session. Restoring the sessions after a restart will fill the view with a bunch of stale crap that will conflict with a possibly newly built view state by the JSF runtime. It ends up confusing the runtime